# How do I structure data for POST from form in ReactJS?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, reactjs

I have a basic React component for a contact form that issues a POST to an API endpoint (using Django REST Framework). That endpoint handles the actual sending, and such.

I'm using jQuery to handle the Ajax business -- I know this is overkill; it will be removed later -- but I can't seem to grok how to structure the values from the form in my component for submission to my endpoint.

Here's my component:

```
var ContactForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      url: '',
    };
  },
  handleNameChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
  },
  handleEmailChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({email: e.target.value})
  },
  handleMessageChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({message: e.target.value})
  },
  handleURLChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({url: e.target.value})
  },
  handleFormSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.state.name.trim();
    var email = this.state.email.trim();
    var message = this.state.message.trim();
    var url = this.state.url.trim();
    if (url) {
      return;
    };
    if (!name || !email || !message) {
      return;
    };
    var formData = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      message: message
    };
    this.props.onContactFormSubmit({formData});
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      url: ''
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit} method="POST">
        <div>
          <label for="id_name">Name:</label>
          <input onChange={this.handleNameChange} id="id_name" maxlength="200" name="name" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
          <input onChange={this.handleEmailChange} id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="id_message">Message:</label>
          <textarea onChange={this.handleMessageChange} cols="40" id="id_message" name="message" rows="10" />
          <span className="helptext">Note: Plain text only. All HTML will be stripped and content escaped on submission.</span>
        </div>
        <div className="honeypot">
          <label for="id_url">Url:</label>
          <input onChange={this.handleURLChange} id="id_url" name="url" type="text" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Send</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
});
var ContactFormContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
  onContactFormSubmit: function (formData) {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('Posted correctly', data)
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <ContactForm onContactFormSubmit={this.onContactFormSubmit} />
    );
  }
});
var communicationCreateUrl = $('#contact_form_container').data('url');
ReactDOM.render(
    <ContactFormContainer url={communicationCreateUrl} />,
    document.getElementById('contact_form_container')
);
```

This results in a dict on the Django side:

```
{'formData[name]': 'Patrick', 'formData[email]': 'patrick@gmail.com', 'formData[message]': 'This is a test.'}
```

What I need is something like this, which is the result of POSTing with this request (`message=Some+test&name=Patrick+Beeson&email=patrickbeeson%40gmail.com`) akin to calling `serialize()` in jQuery:

```
{'name': 'Patrick', 'message': 'This is a test', 'email': 'patrick@gmail.com'}
```

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax Post to send `JSON` to Django and then handle the arguments as a `dict()`. Here is an example:

In browser (JQuery/JavaScript):

```
    function newModule() {

        var my_data = $("#my_element").val(); // Whatever value you want to be sent.

        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'modules' %}",       // Handler as defined in Django URLs. 
            type: "POST",                     // Method.
            dataType: "json",                 // Format as JSON (Default).
            data: {
                path: my_data,                // Dictionary key (JSON). 
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: 
                         '{{ csrf_token }}'   // Unique key.
            },

            success: function (json) {

                // On success do this.

            },

            error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {

                // On failure do this. 

            }

        });
```

In server engine (Python):

```
def handle(request):

    # Post request containing the key.  
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'my_data' in request.POST.keys():

        # Retrieving the value.
        my_data = request.POST['my_data']

    # ...
```

Comment: Well, sure. This is a straightforward approach. But I'd rather structure the data better on the front-end than try and make up for it on the back-end. Thoughts?

Comment: You are structuring the data, as JSON. Send an entire JSON structured array, and get a dict in your engine!